# Does a query optimizer convert expressions to constants when the expression does not involve a column

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I have queries that are similar to:

```
-- MySQL Query
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE start_date >= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - INTERVAL 7 DAY

-- MSSQL Query
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE start_date >= GETDATE() - 7
```

Since the expression on the right hand side does not depend on the column values, should I expect the query optimizer to optimize it into a constant value such as:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE start_date >= '2012-04-28 14:54:31'
```

Or should I calculate the constants and build a query using code.

Comment: A database can  do millions of time compares in the time it takes to retrieve one row from disk.  It can do billions of compares in the time it takes for a network packet to travel from a web to a database server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the documentation for MySQL's [`NOW()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/date-and-time-functions.html#function_now) function (for which [`CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_current-timestamp) is a synonym):

> [`NOW()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/date-and-time-functions.html#function_now) returns a constant time that indicates the time at which the statement began to execute. (Within a stored function or trigger, [`NOW()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/date-and-time-functions.html#function_now) returns the time at which the function or triggering statement began to execute.) This differs from the behavior for [`SYSDATE()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_sysdate), which returns the exact time at which it executes.

As such, the query optimiser will treat it as a constant, as desired.  One can [see this](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a4f05/3) in the `EXPLAIN` output.

I can't speak for MSSQL, although perhaps [this blog](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/andrew_kelly/archive/2008/02/27/when-getdate-is-not-a-constant.aspx) is worth a read?

Answer (score -1):

You have a function on the right side, not a constant. The query must be reevaluated each time...

(do i miss a point ??)

EDIT

Like @Martin and @eggyval kindly explained i really did miss a point. The question is very clearly not about a compile time optimization, so i leave this poor, poor remark as a monument to what should happen to a jerk like me...

Comment: You may have your reasons for downvoting, but please explain. If you prepare this expression and evaluate with a one hour difference, do you expect the same result (static optimization)? Or are you talking about a "single query instance" where evaluating the condition, when applied to each candidate, must be the same (and as such is evalauted once per query, a dynamic optimization).

Comment: The "query optimiser" (which this question is about) only optimises a "single query instance".

Comment: So, how do you call the optimizer that makes static optimizations - like removing real constants (which the question also mentions)...